# Javascript output an error message on each offending control

Tags: javascript, validation

I have to validate these fields in various ways. What I'm really having trouble with is that I have to output an error message for each field if its blank. There should be an error message next to each control that is null. all error messages need to be presented at the same time. So if there are multiple fields blank, all error messages need to show up when the user clicks the validate button.

```
<form name="myForm" action="" onsubmit="formValidate()" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
<br>
Phone: <input type="text" name="area" id="area">-
<input type="text" name="prefix" id="prefix">-
<input type="text" name="suffix" id="suffix">
<br>
Address: <input type="text" name="address" id="address">
<br>
City: <input type="text" name="city" id="city">
State: <select id="state">
        <option value="WI">WI</option>
        <option value="IL">IL</option>
        <option value="MI">MI</option>
    </select>
Zip: <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip">
<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" id="gender">Male

<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" id="gender">Female
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="courses" value="asp" id="asp">ASP.NET
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="courses" value="java" id="java">Advanced Java
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="courses" value="php" id="php">PHP
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Validate">
</form>
```

I've tried adding my own output with appendChild but I couldn't get it to work. I cannot use innerHTML for this, and my overall javascript knowledge is a few years rusty.

Even vague examples will help at this point.

Comment: use `required` attribute for `input` tag..Check this http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

Comment: why don't you use a plugin that already does that? http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code:

### HTML

```
<form name="myForm" action="" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/><span id="nameError" class="error"></span>
    <br/>
    Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/><span id="emailError" class="error"></span>
    <br/>
    Phone: <input type="text" name="area" id="area"/>-
    <input type="text" name="prefix" id="prefix"/>-
    <input type="text" name="suffix" id="suffix"/><span id="phoneError" class="error"></span>
    <br/>
    Address: <input type="text" name="address" id="address"/><span id="addressError" class="error"></span>
    <br/>
    City: <input type="text" name="city" id="city"/><span id="cityError" class="error"></span>
    <br/>
    State: <select id="state">
        <option value="WI">WI</option>
        <option value="IL">IL</option>
        <option value="MI">MI</option>
    </select>
    Zip: <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip"/><span id="zipError" class="error"></span>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" id="gender"/>Male

    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" id="gender"/>Female
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="courses" value="asp" id="asp"/>ASP.NET
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="courses" value="java" id="java"/>Advanced Java
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="courses" value="php" id="php"/>PHP
    <br/>
    <input id="validate" type="submit" value="Validate"/>
</form>
```

### CSS

```
.error {
    color:red;
    font-style:italic;
    font-size:90%;
    padding-left:3px;
}
```

### JavaScript

```
window.VALIDATE_MAP = {
    'name':'nameError',
    'email':'emailError',
    'area':'phoneError',
    'prefix':'phoneError',
    'suffix':'phoneError',
    'address':'addressError',
    'city':'cityError',
    'zip':'zipError'
};
window.BLANK_ERROR_MESSAGE = 'cannot be blank.';

$('#validate').click(function() {
    var valid = true;
    for (var id in VALIDATE_MAP) {
        if (!VALIDATE_MAP.hasOwnProperty(id)) continue;
        var errorId = VALIDATE_MAP[id];
        var $input = $('#'+id);
        var $error = $('#'+errorId);
        if ($input.val() === '') {
            $error.text(BLANK_ERROR_MESSAGE);
            valid = false;
        } else {
            $error.text('');
        } // end if
    } // end for
    return valid;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h4cw4hw7/1/